# How can i use SQLSMO

Tags: c++-cli

i am usnig visual studio2003 and windows platform sdk2008. ihave to migrate from SQLDMO to SQLSMO in c++. do i need any header files for this to use sqlsmo in c++.

can any body help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use SQL SMO from Visual Studio 2003 / .NET 1.1 - SQL SMO requires at least .NET 2.0.

Marc